# Left Function Compile Error: Argument not optional (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a few things with this subroutine.
First i need to insert a row after every 18th row
Then i need to insert a string in column A based on the string in the above row (i.e. 17th row in the first iteration). 
Finally i need to insert a string in column B of the ith row again based on the previously established string.

So in Layman's terms, row 17 will say 120F_CASH
i want to find "_ " and take the characters in the string from the left of the "_ ", then in row 18 i want to put 120F & "_MULTI_STRAT" in column A
in column B of row 18, i want to insert "SSELECT PERF.IMST.INDEX WITH ENTITY = " & "120F" & "AND WITH CATEGORY1 = ""01"""

here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRowEveryXrows()
Dim r As Long, lr As Long
Dim code As String

lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 18 To lr Step 18
        Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Set code = Left(Range(Cells(r - 1, "A"), InStr(1, "_", Cells(r, "A")) - 1))
        Cells(r, "A") = code & "_MULTI_STRAT"
        Cells(r, "B") = "SSELECT PERF.IMST.INDEX WITH ENTITY = " & code & "AND WITH CATEGORY1 = ""01"""
    Next r
End Sub
```

i am getting a compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments on this line:

> Set code = Left(Range(Cells(r - 1, "A"), InStr(1, "_", Cells(r, "A"))
>   - 1))

the string's location is in row 17 (r-1) in column A & the number of characters is found by looking for "_"

What am i missing?
*fyi i had to add a space after the underscore for it to show up properly here, however, there SHOULD NOT be a space after the underscore.

Comment: Delete the set.  Set is only used when assigning to reference variables (e.g. objects).  String is not a reference variablet.

Comment: I think you're brackets are wrong too `Range(Cells(r - 1, "A")` needs to be `Cells(r - 1, "A")` or just `split(Cells(r - 1, "A"),"_")(0)`

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Set code = Left(Range(Cells(r - 1, "A"), InStr(1, "_", Cells(r, "A")) - 1))
> ```

The `Left` function wants a string and an integer, but you haven't provided the integer. Here's the same expression, without the outer `Left` function call:

```
Set code = Range(Cells(r - 1, "A"), InStr(1, "_", Cells(r, "A")) - 1)
```

Notice anything? The result of `InStr` is being passed as the 2nd argument to the (unqualified) `Range` property, and that isn't what you intended.

In fact, you don't need that `Range` call at all. This should be closer to your intent:

```
Set code = Left(Cells(r - 1, "A"), InStr(1, "_", Cells(r, "A")) - 1)
```

Note that there is quite a bit of implicit code going on here; made explicit, reads like this:

```
Set code = Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(r - 1, "A").Value, InStr(1, "_", ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value) - 1)
```

Do you really intend to be working of just whatever worksheet happens to be active? Most likely not, but if so, consider explicitly qualifying these `Cells` calls with `ActiveSheet`. If you mean to be working with a specific sheet, use that sheet object as a qualifier instead.

Now, you're using `Set` for this assignment, but `code` is not an object reference, and that is another problem.

Strings are not objects in VBA, they're assigned with the regular value assignment syntax. That is, without a `Set` keyword (you could have the legacy `Let` keyword there if you wanted, but it's not needed):

```
code = Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(r - 1, "A").Value, InStr(1, "_", ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value) - 1)
```

Now, `Range.Value` (explicit here, implicit in your code) will be a `Variant`, not a `String`. In *most* cases, it won't matter.

Until one cell has a `Variant/Error` subtype (think `#N/A`, or `#VALUE!` worksheet errors); then everything blows up with a *type mismatch* error. To avoid this, you can use the `Text` of the cell instead of its `Value`, or you can pull that value into its own local `Variant` variable, and only proceed to treat it like a string when `IsError` returns `False` for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so

```
Function Pop_String(strInput As String, strDelim As String, Optional lngInstance = 1)

Dim aTemp() As String

aTemp = Split(strInput, strDelim, lngInstance + 1)

Pop_String = aTemp(lngInstance - 1)

End Function
```

Calling like so

`Pop_String("a-b-c-d-e-f","-",4)` returns d
`Pop_String("a-b-c-d-e-f","-",2)` returns b

I would add some error checking too, the default (without 3rd argument) is the first section, so

`Pop_String("test-string","-")` would return test and 
`Pop_String("test-string","-",2)` would return string.